# Where did she hide the gift?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

It's Christmas soon and you're excited. This year your friend was creative and created a riddle for you.

Find your gift. What does the drawing say?

[image]

(source: myself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gift is hidden:

> IN THE BASEMENT

Because:

> The signs look like clocks, with 12 different positions.
>  The positions read: 8, [1], -, [7], 7, 4, -, 1, 0, [6], 4, [0], 4, [1], [7]
>  We can translate them to letters the following way:
>  Add 1 to each number
>  Add 12 to each circled number
>  a '-' is a space
>  Resulting in:
>  9, 14, -, 20, 8, 5, -, 2, 0, 19, 5, 13, 5, 14, 20
>  Which gives the answer written above

Now go and run to get the gift!

Comment: Gah! Beat me to it by a minute!

Comment: Nice job. Too easy I suppose. I seem to not find the right difficulty, either it is too hard or too easy.